# Cage nut sizes: is 10-32 the same as M5?

Tags: rack

For an old 19" rack, I need to buy some cage nuts for round holes. You can't get them here in the Netherlands, it seems, but [Amazon has them](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JCP54A). However, I don't want to get US sized thread...

Amazon says that the above product is 10-32 (US size) and M5 (metric size), but [this PDF](http://www.stayonline.com/whitepapers/SOL-WP-Cage-Nuts.pdf) states that a M5 bolt in a 10-32 nut will strip the thread ("The screw can be forced into the nut but the thread is stripped").

So, does anybody know if they are indeed M5?

Or, does anybody know a Dutch supplier? I've asked a whole bunch, but no one has them anymore...

Answer (score 2):

There's no precise M5 equivalent but I think you'll be fine with either a 10-32 or 10-24 depending on TPI, they're cheap so just buy both and be careful with the first one. No idea on a supplier in NL though sorry - oh and consider changing out the four mounting poles to square ones - they may not be too expensive and would mean you wouldn't have to worry about this problem again.

Good luck.

Comment: I don't think changing the poles in that rack is going to be possible. You're right though, it would be a lot easier... But about the stripping of the thread, you don't think that's going to be much of a problem? Won't I get annoying situations like fiddling with rails in my hand and screws that don't fit easily and therefore drop all the time?

Comment: I would suggest a run to the hardware store. Grab one of each and see what threads. They are definitely different, and you don't want to compromise integrity...

Comment: You can't really get US threads here. But, I've gathered enough info to know that it's not really going to work.

Answer (score 1):

They are an american thread. If you use a metric bolt you will strip the thread guaranteed.  I've got some as I stock occassionally have to work on these.

Answer (score 1):

10-32 and M5 are almost identical. If you're not putting much weight on the rails, you can force one into the other. It will result in minor damage to both the bolt and nut, but it works. I've done this in a pinch, but wouldn't recommend it if you have the opportunity to get the right size.

Answer (score 1):

M5 screws are a few thousands of an inch larger than #10 screws
A 10-32 screw will fit into a M5 nut with a small amount play but a M5 screw being a bit larger will be thght if it fits at all into a 10-32 nut
I would think a person could use a M5 tap to increase the size of a 10-32 nut fairly easily since it is just a bit smaller than the M5

Answer (score 0):

These must have been M5 nuts.  10/32 is slightly smaller in diameter than M5.  You can use a 10/32 screw in an M5 nut pretty safely.  The inverse is not true.